# intellij does not update version from content root

Tags: java, svn, version-control, intellij-idea

I have a project on intellij where i add some content roots from some external modules. now all of these are version controlled. (i.e. they are all in svn). but when want to check in some of the contents of the added content roots (after editing them), intellij wont show me the versions of these files. any clue what about i have to do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

To associate a directory with a version control system

```
Open the Version Control settings page. This page displays a table of directories and the version control systems associated with them.

Note

By default, the table contains only one row for the <Project Root>, with no version control system assigned to it.
Click the Add button. The Add VCS Directory Mapping dialog box opens.
Type the path to the desired directory, or click browseButton to the right of the Directory field and navigate to the desired directory.
From the VCS list, select the version control system to be used for controlling files in this directory.

Tip

Optionally, click the Configure VCS button. The Version Control Configurations dialog box opens where you can configure settings for the selected version control system (see the corresponding configuration settings in the Version Control settings page reference for details).
Click OK to save the mapping and return to the Version Control page.
```

Reference: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/associating-a-directory-with-a-specific-version-control-system.html

Thanks for your time (Whoever read the question)